# Laravel Queries / Controller Edits

Tags: sql, laravel

So I am pretty new to Laravel, and I have spent the whole day fishing through various documentations but I am stuck on the way queries work within the actual application. Right now, I am trying to get some data in my database to display, and I looked at the query builder so that's where I am right now. I am also using a CRUD based admin panel for entry in the database. And since it is CRUD based, it has created the model and the controller already, so I am wondering if I need to edit any of those files to get this to work. Here is what the `public function index()` has right now (Using Laraadmin):

```
    $module = Module::get('Events');

    if(Module::hasAccess($module->id)) {
        return View('la.events.index', [
            'show_actions' => $this->show_action,
            'listing_cols' => $this->listing_cols,
            'module' => $module
        ]);
    } else {
        return redirect(config('laraadmin.adminRoute')."/");
    }`
```

Obviously, I am trying to display some data from this Events table into my blade view. From what I was reading, I understood (or I thought) that it would be something similar to this:

```
foreach ($module as $module) {
   echo $module->id;
}
```

But, I keep getting an error that whatever variable I pass in the loop is undefined, although I thought it was in the controller. Right now my model is just returning the view as well. Any help with this is greatly appreciated, or even just an explanation of the relationships with queries in Laravel. Thanks!

Comment: So what happens if you put {{ dd($module) }} in your  events/index.blade.php ?

Comment: Same error. `Undefined variable: module (View: /Users/WillGuisbond/sites/zdcnew/resources/views/events.blade.php)`

Comment: Then you're not putting it in the right blade. Because it's definitely passed down to it by the controller.

Comment: Ok. So I'm putting it into the events.blade.php file. Maybe the controller isn't linked properly or something? Or maybe the template would work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things to check when this happens:

1. Change module to a known array. This tests if your data array is set up correctly:

   `'module' => [ '1', '2', '3' ], // previously $module`

Within the blade, now write a simple loop, such as:

```
@foreach ($module as $m)
  {{ $m }}
@endforeach
```

If this version does work, then you know you have something up with your $module variable.

2. If the above still doesn't work, try to simplify your view request (temporarily):

   `view('foo', ['a' => 555]);`

Then in `foo.blade.php`, simply have:

```
hello {{ a }}
```

**EDIT**

3. If all this seems to be correct, then the data being fetched is probably wrong (so its not a view issue). Try `$module = Module::all();`

Comment: Ok so It seems that the problem is with the foreach statement in events.blade.php because I don't get an error if I just edit something in the controller. That's when I get the undefined var message.

Comment: So if you pass ['1','2','3'] it will print out correctly in the view?

Comment: No.. Seems like $module is the problem

Comment: Wait, no in the sense - that even with the simple array, it still doesn't work?

Comment: No... Like I said it's a 3rd party CRUD system so maybe I have the variable wrong totally?

Comment: Alright, looks like I was wrong. That simple array is passing through. So now what would I have to do to get the actual intended contents to display?

Comment: See my update, problems like this are about narrowing down *where* something is not working - we now know that you are calling the right blade and were able to pass data. So something is wrong in your controller or your request for data

Comment: Did some more digging and got it to work. Seems like the query builder in the controller was set up incorrectly. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are returning a view that doesn't exist. If what you have now was correct, it would be looking for `resources/views/la/events/index.blade.php` Try replacing that `return view` line with this:

```
return view('events', [ ... rest of your variables ]);
```

And just a side note, on your `foreach` statement, it's probably best to use two separate variable names... so something like:

```
foreach ($module as $element) { ...
```

Comment: Ok so It seems that the problem is with the foreach statement in events.blade.php because I don't get an error if I just edit something in the controller. That's when I get the undefined var message.